# JavaScript / CSS overflow-x not stretching around floated elements

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a basic GUI for a JavaScript web app, that lets users use the web app on any device, without putting too much time and effort into making it too responsive. I figured I could easily use basic overflow properties for container divs, so the user can scroll to the desired button, rather than changing the layout completely for different screen resolutions.

I'm trying to make the top toolbar (File, Edit, Insert etc..) with an overflow-x set to scroll, which holds divs floated to the left. For some reason, the overflow-x does nothing, so some of the buttons are hidden. Why is this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShadeSpeed/Djk4C/)

```
    // STYLE WINDOW
document.body.style.margin = "0px";
document.body.style.padding = "0px";
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#66666A";
document.body.style.color = "#0099AA";
document.body.style.fontFamily = "calibri, sans-serif";

function getScrollbarWidth()
{var o = document.createElement('div');o.style.overflowY = "scroll";o.style.visibility = "none";var i = document.createElement('div');o.appendChild(i);document.body.appendChild(o);var r = o.offsetWidth-i.offsetWidth;o.parentNode.removeChild(o);return(r);}

function getScrollbarHeight()
{var o = document.createElement('div');o.style.overflowX = "scroll";o.style.visibility = "none";document.body.appendChild(o);var r = o.offsetHeight;o.parentNode.removeChild(o);return(r);}

// CREATE EDITOR TOOLBAR
toolbar = document.createElement('div');
toolbar.style.position = "fixed";
toolbar.style.top = "0px";
toolbar.style.left = "0px";
toolbar.style.width = "100%";
toolbar.style.height = 32+getScrollbarHeight()+"px";
toolbar.style.overflowX = "scroll";
toolbar.style.overflowY = "hidden";
toolbar.style.backgroundColor = "#33333A";
toolbar.buttons = {};
toolbar.addButton = function(buttonName){
    var newButton = document.createElement('div');
    newButton.style.width = "128px";
    newButton.style.height = "16px";
    newButton.style.float = "left";
    newButton.style.paddingTop = "8px";
    newButton.style.paddingBottom = "8px";
    newButton.style.textAlign = "center";
    newButton.style.fontSize = "15px";
    newButton.style.color = ";DD8800";
    newButton.innerHTML = buttonName;
    this.buttons[buttonName] = newButton;
    this.appendChild(newButton);
}

toolbar.addButton("File");
toolbar.addButton("Edit");
toolbar.addButton("Insert");
toolbar.addButton("Settings");
toolbar.addButton("Share");
toolbar.addButton("Help");

// CREATE EDITOR WINDOW SELECTOR
windowSelector = document.createElement('div');
windowSelector.style.position = "fixed";
windowSelector.style.top = 32+getScrollbarHeight()+"px";
windowSelector.style.left = "0px";
windowSelector.style.bottom = "0px";
windowSelector.style.width = 128+getScrollbarWidth()+"px";
windowSelector.style.overflowY = "scroll";
windowSelector.style.backgroundColor = "#33333A";
windowSelector.buttons = {};
windowSelector.addButton = function(buttonName,imageURL){
    this.buttons[buttonName] = document.createElement('div');
    this.buttons[buttonName].style.width = "128px";
    this.buttons[buttonName].style.height = "64px";
    this.buttons[buttonName].style.backgroundColor = "#22222A";
    this.buttons[buttonName].style.borderTop = "1px solid #115588";

    var buttonImage = document.createElement('div');
    buttonImage.style.width = "32px";
    buttonImage.style.height = "32px";
    buttonImage.style.margin = "8px";
    buttonImage.style.marginTop = "16px";
    buttonImage.style.marginBottom = "16px";
    buttonImage.style.float = "left";
    buttonImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+imageURL+"')";
    buttonImage.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
    buttonImage.style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
    this.buttons[buttonName].appendChild(buttonImage);

    var buttonTitle = document.createElement('div');
    buttonTitle.style.width = "72px";
    buttonTitle.style.height = "16px";
    buttonTitle.style.paddingTop = "24px";
    buttonTitle.style.paddingBottom = "24px";
    buttonTitle.style.paddingLeft = "8px";
    buttonTitle.style.float = "left";
    buttonTitle.style.color = "#77BBDD";
    buttonTitle.style.fontSize = "14px";
    buttonTitle.innerHTML = buttonName;
    this.buttons[buttonName].appendChild(buttonTitle);

    this.appendChild(this.buttons[buttonName]);
}

windowSelector.addButton("Sprites","");
windowSelector.addButton("Objects","");
windowSelector.addButton("Scripts","");
windowSelector.addButton("Rooms","");
windowSelector.addButton("Backgrounds","");
windowSelector.addButton("Sounds","");
windowSelector.addButton("Paths","");
windowSelector.addButton("Timelines","");
windowSelector.addButton("Constants","");

// CREATE APPLICATION SCRIPT
application = document.createElement('script');

document.body.appendChild(application);
document.body.appendChild(toolbar);
document.body.appendChild(windowSelector);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements will only overflow horizontally if they have no other choice. Usually this is a good thing, but in some cases... yeah.

`float`s will wrap. Instead, try using `display:inline-block` on the items, and `white-space:nowrap` on the container.

This will force the elements to overflow horizontally.

Comment: Thank you very much, at first i didnt think this worked, but I forgot to remove the float styling. Excellent, worked brilliantly. Thank you again.